# Angular checkbox not updating to checked in the view

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, checkbox, angularjs-directive

I am using chrome.

This is my html code

```
ng-repeat="tag in formData.amenities"><label><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="tag.enabled">{{tag.text}}:{{tag.enabled}}
```

I am able to collect tag values when I check/uncheck from the view. The problem is in reverse binding.

I am reading the values back and then applying to the above code. I can see that tag.enabled is set to true but the view doesnt show checked.

I have tried `$scope.apply` but even that doesnt update the view.

Comment: Put `ng-checked="tag.enabled"` in your HTML

Comment: It's working fine http://jsbin.com/jaruki/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/jaruki/2/edit?html,js,output)

Use `ng-checked` directive

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

  <div ng-repeat="tag in formData.amenities">
    <label>Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="tag.enabled" ng-model="tag.enabled">{{tag.text}}:{{tag.enabled}}
    </label>
    </div>

</body>
```

In Controller:

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {
        amenities: [{
            "text": "First",
             "enabled": true
        }, {
            "text": "second",
            "enabled": false
        }, {
            "text": "Thid",
            "enabled": true
        }]
    };
});
```

Comment: Doesnt work. If I add ng-checked everything becomes checked even if it enabled is false.

Comment: Please check demo, you will get the point. Also structure your object accordingly